# File-not found exception while adding multi-Image

Tags: codenameone

Hi, it shows an error while saving the theme file after add multi-image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the File menu uncheck the "XML Team Mode". I guess there's a problem with saving that file to the filesystem but without the team mode it doesn't really matter.